# LayoutParams crashes app

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have strange problem.

Using this code, I get crash when try to make new LayoutParams, before "Error 5".

```
    getScreenWidthAndHeight();
    Log.d("Error", "1");
    eField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailField);
    Log.d("Error", "2");
    pField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
    Log.d("Error", "3");
    signInButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.singInButton); 
    Log.d("Error", "4");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParamsForEField = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(eField.getWidth(), eField.getHeight());
    Log.d("Error", "5");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParamsForPField = (LayoutParams) pField.getLayoutParams();
    Log.d("Error", "6");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParamsForSignInButton = (LayoutParams) signInButton.getLayoutParams();
```

**CLOSED**

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Problem was in trying to find element before set layout for content view.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Just posted it. NullPointerException... very interesting.

Comment: Everything points that, but it is in main_activity.xml . Maybe problem hides in using several layouts for different screens. I just checked all ids in them.

Comment: Can view's ids have the same id name in layouts for different screens? For example in main_activity.xml for medium screen there is a button with id "sing_in" and in main_activity.xml for large screens?

Comment: You cut the log right at the point where the useful info begins =)
Please, post the line just under "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: post your import package code.. I think you import wrong layoutparams